# Reportview export to pdf missing alt tags

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, reportviewer

I'm working with reportviewer in vs2008, whey I try to export my report to pdf it is creating pdf successfully..

But here my problem is when I'm exporting my pdf file is missing alt tags for images which is previously there in my report. In my reportviewer it is showing alt tags for every image. But in pdf it is not showing any alt tag for images.

Can somebody help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have the same problem in exporting to Excel?

Comment: No even for the excel also it is not working